# Scala existentials - type mismatch, unable to infer T =:= T

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, existential-type

When using existential types in Scala, it seems the compiler infers each usage of the existential to be a different type parameter, even if they are actually the same.

For a simple contrived example - Given the following code

```
class Box[T](value:T){
  def get:T = value
  def contains(check:T):Boolean = value == check
}
```

I can do the following

```
val b1 = new Box(1)
b1.contains(b1.get)
```

However when using existential types...

```
 val b2 : Box[_] = new Box(1)
 b2.contains(b2.get)
```

I get the following error (In scala 2.11.7

```
[error] /private/tmp/exttest/test.scala:53: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (some other)_$6(in value b2)
[error]  required: _$6(in value b2)
[error]   b2.contains(b2.get)
```

My assumption would be that the compiler would understand that the same type parameter `_$6` is in use in both cases, however it seems to lose track and treat these as seperate types.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about existential types, or is this a bug in the Scala compiler - and if so, is there a best-practice to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use type variable patterns to give a name to the wildcard and help Scala figure out they are the same:

```
val b2 : Box[_] = new Box(1)
b2 match {
  case b: Box[a] => b.contains(b.get)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is probably more of a limitation rather than a bug.

Often easy way to work around this is to move the sensitive code to a generic method:

```
def containsSelf[T](box: Box[T]): Boolean =
  box.contains(box.get)

val b2 : Box[_] = new Box(1)
containsSelf(b2)
```

Or design your class with type members instead of generics. This may be a bit more boilerplate-y but does exactly what you want:

```
trait Box {
  type Element
  def get: Element
  def contains(check: Element): Boolean
}
object Box {
  type Aux[T] = Box { type Element = T }
  def apply[T](value: T): Box.Aux[T] =
    new Box {
      type Element = T
      def get = value
      def contains(check: T) = value == check
    }
}

val b2: Box = Box(1)
b2.contains(b2.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the type bound on `check` in `def contains(check:T):Boolean = value == check` restricts the matching.

I get the following when I apply a workaround like so:

```
scala> class Box[T](value:T){
     |  def get:T = value
     |  def contains(check:X forSome { type X}):Boolean = value == check
     | }
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
defined class Box

scala> val b1 = new Box(1)
b1: Box[Int] = Box@745d86ec

scala> b1.contains(b1.get)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> val b2 : Box[_] = new Box(1)
b2: Box[_] = Box@5bd46b54

scala>  b2.contains(b2.get)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: This is pretty much equivalent to having `def contains(check: Any)`

Comment: Hmm, yeah I guess your solution is more robust.